# register_sidebar() works in wordpress backend but not in frontend

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a custom sidebar to my custom wordpress template.

I added this to my functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar'))
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'          =>  'NiceBar',
    'id'            =>  'sidebar-widget',
    'before_widget' =>  '<li>',
    'after_widget'  =>  '</li>',
    'before_title'  =>  '<h2>',
    'after_title'   =>  '</h2>',
    ));
```

This to my sidebar.php:

`<ul class="sidebar">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('NiceBar') ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>`

And this to my index.php:

`<?php get_sidebar('NiceBar'); ?>`

Now the result is, though I am getting a sidebar it's just a default one and not my custom 'NiceBar' on the frontend. In the wordpress backend the 'NiceBar' is registered and I can and remove stuff to it but it hast just no influence on my website.

Any kind of advice is very welcome

Comment: Are you correct in template? Or checking  in wrong template?

Comment: I'm in the correct template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing your sidebar by name, instead you should get it via id :

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-widget'); ?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just tried it that way, but it won't work.

Comment: Try to remove the minus from id, make it sidebarWidget

Comment: from codex : id - Sidebar id - Must be all in lowercase, with no spaces (default is a numeric auto-incremented ID). If you do not set the id argument value, you will get E_USER_NOTICE messages in debug mode, starting with version 4.2.

Comment: after you changed the sidebar ID you need to place widgets again

Comment: ye, he should show nothing after that on my frontend, but he's still showing that nasty default sidebar. the default sidebar consists of Search / Pages / Archives / Categories / Meta

Comment: As you said, my 'NiceBar' was empty in the backend after I changed the ID but it didn't change anything on my website.

Comment: Thank you guys. Problem is solved. He couldn't read my sidebar.php because it was in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**functions.php**

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name'          =>  'NiceBar',
            'id'            =>  'sidebar-widget',
            'before_widget' =>  '<li>',
            'after_widget'  =>  '</li>',
            'before_title'  =>  '<h2>',
            'after_title'   =>  '</h2>',
            ));
}
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<ul class="sidebar">
       <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
            dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-widget');   
       }  ?>
</ul>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Problem is in the `get_sidebar()` function you are telling that in your theme there is a file called: sidebar-sidebar-widget.php because you are passing argument sidebar-widget in the `get_sidebar()` function. [read it here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)